# Group By when the count > 100 Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following class

```java
private class MaintWindowClass {
    String SiteID;
    String Node;

    public String getSiteID() {
        return SiteID;
    }

    public String getNode() {
        return Node;
    }
}
```

A node can have multiple sites. I am trying to get Nodes whose site count > 100.

Is it possible to get via Streams. So far I have tried these

```java
ArrayList<MaintWindowClass> maintWindowArray = new ArrayList<MaintWindowClass>(); // then add some MaintWindowClass in it. 
Map<String, Long> sitesGroupedCount = maintWindowArray.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MaintWindowClass::getNode, 
        Collectors.counting())); // More appropriate this breaks sites in to Nodes and the site count in it.
```

I can now iterate this Map and get those nodes which has sitecount > 100 but is it possible to just get those nodes in which site count is greater than 100 using streams?

Comment: You have already used `Stream`s, you just needed to iterate further or chain via another stream over entries of the `Map` collected so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have it!
Now you need to iterate over the map and filter the entries according the value:

```
List<String> nodesWithMoreThan100Sites = maintWindowArray.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MaintWindowClass::getNode, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 100)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @VishwaRatna Please do try and keep from posting comments like that; they only distract from the answer, and other voters should make up their own minds.

Comment: @Luis Iñesta Thanks this worked fine. 
First stream to get count then another stream to get count > 100.
I was wondering is it possible get this output from a single stream 
I think running a single stream might give better performance.